# Change table width animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, html-table, width

Is it possible to smoothly animate the width of a table. Ten percent per second would be a good rate. So that it slowly expands and keeps expanding?

On load 
`<table id="01" width="80%" height="769">`

1 second
`<table id="01" width="90%" height="769">`

2 second
`<table id="01" width="100%" height="769">`

3 second
`<table id="01" width="110%" height="769">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `JQuery` you can chain `.animate()`s to get what you want:

```
$('#table').animate({width: '+=' + $(this).width() * 0.1 + 'px'}, 1000).animate({width: '+=' + $(this).width() * 0.1 + 'px'}, 1000).animate({width: '+=' + $(this).width() * 0.1 + 'px'}, 1000).animate({width: '+=' + $(this).width() * 0.1 + 'px'}, 1000);
```

and if you want to increase the size in one step (ie. without delay):

```
$('#table').animate({width: $(this).width() * 1.1 + 'px'}, 4000);
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjqNP/).

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do so. If you are willing to assume html5 supporting browsers, check out css transformations and transitions. Transitions are easier to use for what you need. you can define you css like this:

```
#01 {
    -moz-transition : width 3s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition : width 3s; /* chrome and safari */
    -o-transition: width 3s; /* Opera */
    transition: width 3s;
    width : 80%;
}
#01.growing {
    width : 110%
}
```

Then when you want the transition to start, just add the class "growing" to the element.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dZz44/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible! (easiest answer all day!)

but seriously.. look into javascript smooth resizing? or if you want to use a library there are MANY MANY ui plugins that will do this for most major libraries..

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is the obvious choice for most... however for something this simple I suggest looking into how to do it yourself.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/sNBJp/) is a quick example in jQuery

Comment: Thank you very much that will point me in the right direction!